# css not displaying image when used in php file

Tags: php, css, image

I am trying to display css through a php file. Most things work well until i get to an image i want to display from database. In source code it does accept the value from DB but does not display the image. Image will display if I use regular css. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Here is code.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
include('database connect info here');
include('/session info here');

sec_session_start();
$numm =$_SESSION['memid'];
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM preff WHERE memid = :memid");
$query->bindParam(':memid', $numm);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$bgimage = $row['backgroundimage'];
?>
body{
 background-image:url('<?=$bgimage?>') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: can we change this <?=$bgimage?> to <?php echo $bgimage; ?> and try

Comment: is it image in same folder as your php file?

Comment: Can you provide the outputted source code?

Comment: the =  or echo both produce the same result. It gets image from DB but does not show image. Yes for simplicity troubleshooting this the image and files are all in same directory.the following is what the view source code shows:      body{
 background-image:url('back.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Does the console show a request being made for `back.jpg`?

Comment: no i dont see a call.

Comment: Your page has a body tag?

Comment: yes it does. standard html setup.

Answer (score 0):

Found at least a work around. Apparently when pulling css from a php file for images, adding width and height helps. just a little note for anyone who may come across the same issue i had. Thanks all for responses.

Comment: Seems like the issue is specific to the usage of the `background-image` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image Testing locally ` background:no-repeat url('<?=$bgimage?>') center center fixed;` worked for me.